# Has setting of DialogResult closing effect on form displayed via ShowDialog()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, modal-dialog, dialogresult

After some changes, my application started to behave unexpectedly: login form displayed as

```
If DialogResult.OK <> New frmLogin().ShowDialog() Then ...
```

is *automatically closing itself* when line marked as `'problem` is included. If I comment in out, it keeps itself open (as it worked before changes) until I call `Me.Close()`manually.

```
Private Sub Login_Click()
    If My.Application.appSession.ID > 0 Then
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()
    Else
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort 'problem
        MsgBox("Invalid user name or password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
End Sub
```

Did you observe described behavior, that purely setting value of `DialogResult` property closes the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the form displayed you need to set it in this way

```
Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None
```

Every other settings causes the form to close.

In the form class you could read about the [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property

> If the form is displayed as a dialog box, setting this property with a
>   value from the DialogResult enumeration sets the value of the dialog
>   box result for the form, hides the modal dialog box, and returns
>   control to the calling form

Comment: You are right, it was RTFM problem. If you weren't added the answer so quickly, I would have deleted the question.

Comment: Yes it is a simple scenario, nonetheless I think you have expressed well your problem and thus the question could be useful for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for heads-up. I'll keep it for future reference.